# Corner radius to superview subview UIView not shown

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, cornerradius

Added `UIView` of (50 height) to superview i.e., `UIView` a 50 % hold inside remaining outside to superview.

After adding corner radius to superview the below half of bottomView is not shown.

```
extension UIView{

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    bg_view.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20). // MainView
    SearchView.bringSubviewToFront(bg_View)
}
```

Here is storyboard image

[image: d]

Comment: Can you add the storyboard of how they look with different colours to avoid any potential confusion?

Comment: @Rikh added storyboard too

Comment: The answer below is the easiest possible solution to your problem. The `CAShapeLayer` is added on the `bg_view` and causes clipping of all content present inside the `bg_view` but outside the applied `CGPath` which is the bounds of the `bg_view`

Answer (score 0):

You should move green view out of your background view which clips its bounds since your are setting cornerRadius. Your green view can have centerY constraint equal to your backgroundViews bottom. In order to achieve this, you can first define vertical spacing between them and then edit that constraints first item to centerY

[image: View hierarchy]